# How to trigger any of the arrow keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an application (HTML5, JavaScript, Jquery, jquery Mobile) with a slider.
 The handle can be moved via touch and you can navigate through the years 1861 to 2000. There are symbols on my map which are visible/non visible depending on the year. [See my example image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xf04P.png)

I also want the handle to move, when the user clicks a specific button ("forward"). the handle should go through each year until the user clicks a different button.
I managed that with one click the handle goes + 1 year, and the handle, the year and the map update the changed year.

```js
 function moveLeft(){
 var slider1 = $("#slider").val();
 var $slider = $("#slider");
 slider1++;
 $slider.val(slider1).slider("refresh");
 var wert1 = slider1;
  var start = new Date().getTime(); //start = 
  hideLayer2(wert1, start); 
  $('#jahr').text(wert1); 
  var $ausgabe = $("#ausgabe");
  $ausgabe.text(wert1); 
  gewaehltesJahr = wert1;
```

I built a for loop (for (i =slider1; i< 2000; i++)) for this function but the handle and everything will only update, if the function reached the year 2000. I want to see the update of every single year.
Even if I go through the code with a debugger, it will only update year, handle and map when it finished the loop und exited the function.

Following code for example:
If i start in 1861 und initialise the function the handle and map will jump directly into 1870 after the alert "alert("vor") in the last line.

```js
function vor(){ 
 var slider1 = $("#slider").val();
 var $slider = $("#slider");
 for( var s = slider1; s < 1870; s++){ 
  //$slider.val(s).slider("refresh");
  $("#slider").slider('value',s);
  alert(s);
  var wert1 = s;
  var start = new Date().getTime(); //start = aktuelles Datum
  hideLayer2(wert1, start); 
  $('#jahr').text(wert1); 
  var $ausgabe = $("#ausgabe");
  $ausgabe.text(wert1); 
  gewaehltesJahr = wert1;
 }
 alert("vor");
}
```

The handle, when in focus can also be moved by pressing the arrowkeys.

```js
$('.ui-slider-track .ui-btn.ui-slider-handle').focus();
```

I tried du imitate the pressing of one key to go a year forward but it isn't working either.I tried to set a trigger but it didn't work. Can anybody help?

```js
var kEvent = document.createEvent('Event');
 kEvent.initKeyEvent("keypress", true, true, null, false, false, false, false, 38, 0);
 document.activeElement.dispatchEvent(kEvent);
```

Comment: You want to move your slider form current year to max value year, e.g. from 1900 to 2000, in an animate fashion. So it'll give feel that pointer is moving from 1900 to 2000, in say 100 seconds, showing info for each year for 1 second.

Comment: yes that's right!

Comment: For loop will get executed instanly, use interval function to loop with time. I've added an answer with same concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks so much, I edited it a little bit and now it works!

```
   var animation_timer;
function vor(){ 
    animate_slider = true;
    animation_timer = setInterval(function(){
        if(!animate_slider){
            clearInterval(animation_timer);
        }
        else{
            var slider1 = $("#slider").val();
            var $slider = $("#slider");
           // $("#slider").slider('value',slider1);
             slider1++;
            var wert1 = slider1;
            $slider.val(slider1).slider("refresh");
            var start = new Date().getTime(); //start = aktuelles Datum
            hideLayer2(wert1, start); 
            $('#jahr').text(wert1); 
            var $ausgabe = $("#ausgabe");
            $ausgabe.text(wert1); 
            gewaehltesJahr = wert1;
            if(slider1 == 2000){
                clearInterval(animation_timer);
            }
        }
    },1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For loop gets executed instantly, so you have to use javascript timers!

```
//Global flag to decide animation
//Make this false to clear the animation loop from anywhere
var animate_slider = false;

//Global timer for animation
var animation_timer;

//Call animation function
function vor(){ 
    animate_slider = true;
    animation_timer = setInterval(function(){
        if(!animate_slider){
            clearInterval(animation_timer);
        }
        else{
            var slider1 = $("#slider").val();
            var $slider = $("#slider");
            $("#slider").slider('value',s);
            var wert1 = s;
            var start = new Date().getTime(); //start = aktuelles Datum
            hideLayer2(wert1, start); 
            $('#jahr').text(wert1); 
            var $ausgabe = $("#ausgabe");
            $ausgabe.text(wert1); 
            gewaehltesJahr = wert1;
            if(slider1 == maxValue){
                clearInterval(animation_timer);
            }
        }
    },1000);
}
```

**Note:**

Triggering arrow keys is not necessary & pointless, cause it'll also result in instance execution of all clicks. So even there you have to use timers, thus you can bypass that & change you main method with timers.